# Javascript request over XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to download a web page through XHR, and then render it in the browser (using document.write()), but when I do this, although the page is displayed, the jQuery's ready() function does not execute. If I download the exact same page directly, it does execute. Is there something that needs to be done to make the page delivered through XHR execute the ready() function?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write()` to replace page contents, it'll end in tears.

Just find a suitable top-level element and use `.replaceWith()` to get rid of its existing contents and include the new contents retrieved from the XHR, e.g.:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    $(body).replaceWith($(html).find('body'));
});
```

Note that this won't replace the `<head>`, nor will it execute any additional Javascript blocks that might be included in the new content.

You can also use `.load()`

```
$(body).load(url);
```

Comment: Depends on his use case (although I can't think of a good one, too). Using `replaceWith`, DOMready will absolutely not fire again, so that doesn't really answer his question :-)

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure there's any solution that'll automatically fire DOMReady again.

Comment: Not again, of course, but from him using `document.write` I concluded it wouldn't have fired already. Yet, it might fire "again" if you loaded jQuery twice.

Comment: @Bergi I rather suspect that it's his use of `document.write` *after* DOMready that's actually causing his problems.

Comment: That's true. He rather used an `<iframe>` then… But let's look for his code